# IIFE reference error variable not defined inside the function?

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing my js functions and came through an error that is not so obvious for a beginner. The problem is the function won't define my second variable. It works when I declare my variables outside, but I'm interested on the inside. Heres the code.

```
(function (firstname, lastname){
    var firstN = 'Hubba';
    var lastN = 'Bubba';
    console.log(firstname + ' ' + lastname)
}(firstN, lastN));
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here. What do you need those `firstname` and `lastname` variables for? Where should they come from?

Comment: Well yes you cannot pass arguments to an IIFE that don't exist outside of it. If you want to use variables inside the IIFE scope only, don't use parameters.

Comment: You feed your function this 2 variables `firstN`, `lastN`, but they defined inside your function that is wrong, place them outside

Comment: Oh i just wanna make the function work, it should output Hubba Bubba in the console, but it is saying that the variables are not defined.

Comment: You are declaring your variables inside the function, which creates their scope only inside the function (read closers for more ref). and hence it is giving you error of variables are not defined.

Comment: @Zein.Mrwan `console.log('Hubba' + ' ' + 'Bubba')` does that without any variables or IIFEs. `(function() { var firstname = 'Hubba', lastname = 'Bubba'; console.log(firstname + ' ' + lastname) }());` does it with. Why do you want to use even more variables or parameters for the function?

Comment: I know, im trying to understand functions and scopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because inside the function the variables `firstN` and `lastN` are local variables to the functions scope. This means they only exist inside of your function when you execute it.

So when you try to call your function by doing `(function(..){...}(firstN, lastN))` those variables you pass are outside the scope of your function, as such they aren't defined.

For example if I did:

```js
var firstN = 'Hubba_1';
var lastN = 'Bubba_1';
(function (firstname, lastname){
    var firstN = 'Hubba_2'; // Not needed
    var lastN = 'Bubba_2';  // Not needed
    console.log(firstname + ' ' + lastname)
}(firstN, lastN));
```

You will notice that it prints `Hubba_1` and `Bubba_1`. The outside `firstN` and `lastN` are entirely different variables compared to the variables `firstN` and `lastN` inside your function.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i wanted to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for the `firstN` and `lastN` values outside of the scope of your IIFE, which are `undefined` in the outer scope.  Look into how block scope works.

```js
// SO snippets don't allow undefined vars so we can mimic it using `window` like would be in the browser

var window = {};
console.log(window.firstN); //undefined
console.log(window.lastN); //undefined

var firstN = "Foo";
var lastN = "Bar";

(function(firstname, lastname){
  var firstN = "Happy";
  var lastN = "Go Lucky";
  console.log(firstname + " " + lastname); // 'Foo Bar'
  console.log(firstN + " " + lastN); // 'Happy Go Lucky'
})(firstN, lastN)
```